# Selecting node with Data name in powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I have xml file generated from server log, which contains nodes. These nodes can look both like `<Version>0</Version>` and `<Data Name="LogonType">3</Data>`. I have xml loaded into $xmlData variable. When I try to access former,  `$xmlData.Event.System.Version` it displays 0(=correct). But if I try to do that with latter, `$xmlData.Event.EventData.LogonType`, it does not display anything. How does one access the latter?

I did put the variable with loaded xml into foreach and cycled over it to find out names of the objects which it creates for foreach, so the name of the latter should be correct. This way you can get the data from it. How do you get data from the latter directly?

I have included an example of my xml file, but I was unable to format it into viewer friendly form(not one long line, enter broke the code).

```
<Event><System><Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing" Guid="{54849625-5478-4994-a5ba-3e3b0328c30d}"/><EventID>4624</EventID><Version>0</Version><Level>0</Level><Task>12544</Task><Opcode>0</Opcode><Keywords>0x8000000000000000</Keywords><TimeCreated SystemTime="2018-04-18T04:51:55.703563800Z"/><EventRecordID>585</EventRecordID><Correlation/><Execution ProcessID="640" ThreadID="5608"/><Channel>Security</Channel><Computer>Computer name</Computer><Security/></System><EventData><Data Name="SubjectUserSid">S-1-0-0</Data><Data Name="SubjectUserName">-</Data><Data Name="SubjectDomainName">-</Data><Data Name="SubjectLogonId">0x0</Data><Data Name="TargetUserSid">user-id</Data><Data Name="TargetUserName">UserAcc</Data><Data Name="TargetDomainName">DomainName</Data><Data Name="TargetLogonId">tlogId</Data><Data Name="LogonType">3</Data><Data Name="LogonProcessName">Nt </Data><Data Name="AuthenticationPackageName">NTLM</Data><Data Name="WorkstationName">WorkstationName</Data><Data Name="LogonGuid">{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}</Data><Data Name="TransmittedServices">-</Data><Data Name="LmPackageName">NTLM V2</Data><Data Name="KeyLength">keyL</Data><Data Name="ProcessId">0x0</Data><Data Name="ProcessName">-</Data><Data Name="IpAddress">IpAddress</Data><Data Name="IpPort">IpPort</Data></EventData></Event>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"LogonType" is an attribute value, you can not access it like a node or an attribute.

If I understood the question correctly, you can use pipe and filter to read the value of the node data which name attribute value is "logontype" (tested with PowerShell 5) :

```
$xml = [xml]@"...your xml.."
$xml.Event.EventData.Data | ? Name -eq LogonType | % innertext
# output 3
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed. Would you mind explaining what is % innertext? The rest is clear to me.

Comment: % is an alias for [ForEach-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-5.1) , for exemple, all this syntax produce the same output :`Get-Process | ForEach-Object {$_.ProcessName}` or  `Get-Process | % { $_.ProcessName }` or  `Get-Process | %  ProcessName`

Comment: And in this case it was ForEach-Object from $xml.Event.EventData.Data | ? Name -eq LogonType. Yup, that's it, thanks a lot.